# build form for tables with many relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, sonata-admin, many-to-one

I have got a problem to build a forms with many relations between tables. The structure of relations you can see on below picture:[image: relations between tables]

My relations in YML:

```
######### Products.orm.yml #########

   type: entity
   table: products
   fields:
   ...
   lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
   oneToMany:
   productCombinations:
      targetEntity: ProductsCombinations
      mappedBy: product

######### ProductsCombinations.orm.yml #########

   type: entity
   table: products_combinations
   fields:
   ...
   lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
   oneToMany:
      productAttributes:
        targetEntity: ProductsAttributesJoin
        mappedBy: productCombinations
   manyToOne:
      product:
        targetEntity: Products
        inversedBy: productCombinations
        joinColumn:
          name: product_id
          referencedColumnName: id

######### ProductsAttributesJoin.orm.yml ########

type: entity
table: null
fields:
    combinationID:
        type: bigint
        column: combination_id
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: NONE
    attributeID:
        type: bigint
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: NONE
        column: attribute_id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
manyToOne:
    productCombinations:
      targetEntity: ProductsCombinations
      inversedBy: productAttributes
      joinColumn:
        name: combination_id
        referencedColumnName: combination_id
    attributes:
      targetEntity: Attributes
      inversedBy: productAttributesJoin
      joinColumn:
        name: attribute_id
        referencedColumnName: id

######### Attributes.orm.yml #########

   type: entity
   table: products_attributes
   fields:
   ...
   lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
   oneToMany:
      productAttributesJoin:
        targetEntity: ProductsAttributesJoin
        mappedBy: attributes
   manyToOne:
       productAttributesDefinitions:
         targetEntity: AttributesDefinitions
         inversedBy: productAttributes
         joinColumn:
           name: attribute_id
           referencedColumnName: id

######### AttributesDefinitions.orm.yml #########

   type: entity
   table: products_attributes_definitions
   fields:
   ...
   lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
   oneToMany:
      productAttributes:
        targetEntity: Attributes
        mappedBy: productAttributesDefinitions
   manyToOne:
       productAttributesDefinitions:
         targetEntity: AttributesDefinitions
         inversedBy: productAttributes
         joinColumn:
           name: attribute_id
           referencedColumnName: id
```

What I have got know is that:
[image: epos_wrong]

What is not working as when I will click Add new then I got popup with fields from ProductsCombinations but when I will fill them in and press Save then it is showing error that product_id is null (but it should take it from Products).

Also what I would like to do is something like that:
[image]

Also a bit of code from Admin directory:

```
###### ProductsView.php ######

$formMapper->with('Attributes')
            ->add('productCombinations',  'sonata_type_collection')
        ->end()

###### ProductsCombinations.php ######

    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->(some main fields from productCombinations)
            ->add('productAttributes', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
            'sortable'  => 'position'
        ))

###### ProductsAttributesJoin.php ######

    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('attributes', 'sonata_type_model')
        ->end()
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, in you `Product` entity, you have `addProductCombinations` method. Make it like so:

```
public function addProductCombinations($object)
{
    $this->productCombinations[] = $object;
    $object->setProduct($this); // This line is important.
}
```

This should get you moving. Alternatively, you can set product inside `prePersist` / `preUpdate` actions in your admin.

The second part of the question is a bit unclear. Do you want to have attributes that are of different types like text / choice / multiple choice? If so, you will have to dynamically modify the form using [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). But hey, maybe you can reuse some existing bundles, like [packagist: assortment](https://packagist.org/search/?q=assortment).